# Where would one ask questions pertaining to architecture of buildings? (Like the kind Ted Mosby of "How I Met Your Mother" would be interested in)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am not a person who has studied architecture or any form of engineering streams. Just one with cursory interest in decors an building techniques, old and new. The type who watches those *[National Geographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Geographic)* documentaries like 'MegaStructures'

I was looking for a place where I can ask questions about such topics.
For example: "the type of glasses covering typical multistory office buildings" or "How do engineers compensate for metal expansion in large bridges?"

Can anyone direct me to the correct Stack exchange site?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=glass) for questions about glass or metal expansion joints.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure if Engineering applied, or if there was a separate SE for architecture. Does this SE still apply if the questions pertain to definition.  For e.g: "what is the  triangular portion of a wall between the edges of intersecting roof pitches called?"